# How to move changed data, alltered sps and views to different server when not linked

Tags: sql-server

I have made some changes to few tables (data changes), stored procedure and views in a database at DEV server.
I want to copy those changes to a CERT server, but both servers are not linked together.

Can you suggest some way out.

Regards
Arpan Chinmay

Comment: Script data (merge/insert/update) and objects (alter table/view/procedure) and run on second server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools to create scripts for you.

If you own visual studio, you can download SQL Server Data Tools: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Or Redgate has a compare tool:
https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index

These tool will compare the databases and create scripts to update one or the other.

Otherwise, you will have to manually compare each object and write manual SQL to update the schema.